# What are the rules for changing religions?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, sorcerer, forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities

One of my players started as a believer of Bane in Faerun and secretly tried to undermine the group. Now, since the group helped him a lot along the way and saved his life, he helps people while being in the group. This changed his alignment over the years and he lost faith in Bane. He wants to convert to another god now.
He is neither a Paladin nor a Cleric, but a Sorcerer.

I imagine Bane not to let one of his flock go so easily, but since the character isn't a divine spellcaster he can't really punish him by taking away spell-privileges.
I found the rules about Divine Conversion in the Players Handbook on page 193, but they only apply to divine spellcasters. Are there rules for a scenario like this?

Comment: What setting is this? Forgotten Realms—whence Bane originates—has particular rules about faith that are different from every other setting. (The “default setting” such as it is, appears to be Greyhawk with the serial numbers filed off; point is, not Forgotten Realms.)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]! As the other comment mentions, if this question is about a campaign that has the Forgotten Realms as its setting, please edit the question so as to tag it appropriately. If it's not, then please mention that in the question. Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: You say you are looking for rules, but this sounds more like a lore question?

Comment: @Theik Heh, given how much was published over the course of 3.x's reign as the official game, it is  not beyond the realm of possibility that such a rule *was* published.

Answer (score 3):

#### The church of Bane may seek to punish the character for defecting.

Sorcerers don't have to worship a deity to receive spells. Leaving the service of Bane won't affect their abilities. The 3e *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting* also has a section on rules for changing deities, but they only apply for divine casters.

However, the followers of Bane are unlikely to take the defection of one of their members lightly. The core values of Bane's church include control, fear, strict hierarchy, torture, and human sacrifice. Treachery is punished by death. For example, in the D&D 3e *Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting*, p.237-238, Bane's dogma is described as follows:

> Serve no one but Bane. Fear him always and make others fear him even more than you do. The Black Hand always strikes down those that stand against it in the end. **Defy Bane and die**—or in death find loyalty to him, for he shall compel it.

Comment: You should add that this is about lore, not rules.

Answer (score 1):

There is quite an extensive writeup on Bane in *[Dragon Magazine #372](https://archive.org/stream/DragonMagazine260_201801/DragonMagazine372#page/n23/mode/2up)* starting on page 24:

As it notes, the writeup is mostly generic, rather than being specific to a setting:

> **BANE VS. BANE**
>
> The Bane of the core D&D® setting is not the same god as the Bane of the Forgotten Realms® setting! Oh, there’s substantial conceptual overlap. (The matching names probably clued you in on that.) They serve roughly the same purpose in the pantheons, their religious precepts have a great deal in common, and they make use of similar tactics and servitors.
>
> Yet their differences are many as well, especially in terms of personal history, behavior, and even appearance. All that follows describes the core Bane, and it shouldn’t necessarily apply to the Bane of Faerun.

There is no specific lore in this article regarding the departure of a follower, however it does give some examples of Bane's displeasure:

> Omens of Bane’s displeasure include the following:
>
> ♦ Weapons rust and tarnish regardless of how much care is lavished upon them.
>
> ♦ Long-healed wounds ache.
>
> ♦ The worshiper grows clumsy and drops weapons during practice.
>
> ♦ Warhorses, hounds, and other beasts of battle snarl at, and refuse to cooperate with, the individual.

Faiths and Pantheons (Forgotten Realms setting) suggests that leaving the fold would be punished harshly, but again, there is no specific action named:

> **Dogma**: Serve no one but Bane. Fear him always and make others fear him even more than you do. The 'Black Hand' always strikes down those who stand against it in the end. Defy Bane and die - or in death find loyalty to him, for he shall compel it. Submit to the word of Bane as uttered by his ranking clergy, since true power can only be gained through service to him. Spread the dark fear of Bane. it is the doom of those who do not follow him to let power slip through their hands. Those who cross the Black Hand meet their dooms earlier and more harshly than those who worship other deities.

So while there is no specific penalty, the indications are that Bane and/or his representatives will make the PC's life miserable and preferably short.

Answer (score 0):

#### The *Atonement* spell has been referenced in relation to changing which Power with whom one is aligned.

Often, a change in religion is accompanied by a change in alignment. In such cases, there is a built in method: the *Atonement* spell.

The relevant part is quoted here, but the entire spell is worth a read.

> **Redemption or Temptation**
>
> You may cast this spell upon a creature of an opposing alignment in order to offer it a chance to change its alignment to match yours. The prospective subject must be present for the entire casting process. Upon completion of the spell, the subject freely chooses whether it retains its original alignment or acquiesces to your offer and changes to your alignment. No duress, compulsion, or magical influence can force the subject to take advantage of the opportunity offered if it is unwilling to abandon its old alignment. This use of the spell does not work on outsiders or any creature incapable of changing its alignment naturally.
>
> **Though the spell description refers to evil acts, atonement can also be used on any creature that has performed acts against its alignment, whether those acts are evil, good, chaotic, or lawful.**
>
> Note: Normally, changing alignment is up to the player. This use of atonement simply offers a believable way for a character to change his or her alignment drastically, suddenly, and definitively.

http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/atonement.htm

---

Your group seems to have already availed yourselves of the best way to change "alignment" and beliefs... role playing.

As noted, the spell is there more to provide a rules framework for the sudden change to a character stat, than to replace the role playing aspect.